# Why do I get an #N/A error in my XLookUp formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to insert a simple XLookup formula with the lookup value on one sheet and the lookup array and return array on a different sheet. I keep getting a `#N/A` result and I don't understand why.

The lookup value sheet is:

[image]

The array sheet is:

[image]

The formula I'm using is: `=XLOOKUP([@ActivityCode],Query_NameProdAvailCode[Code],Query_NameProdAvailCode[Active])`

My desired outcome is to lookup the "ActivityCode" from the lookup value sheet - in Col C and return the corresponding code from the array sheet Col C.

Example:

For the first row. ActivityCode 4 = N

The result I end up getting is:

[image]

Comment: Make sure the lookup and target values match. extra spaces etc

Comment: @SolarMike yeeep, there seems to have been some invisible spaces after the lookup array's values. I'll add a trim function to clean it up before the XLookUp formula. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the Values have to be of the same type. If `lookup_value` is numeric, and `Lookup_Array` is text, the formula will return an `#N/A` error

Comment: Like Ron Rosenfeld says. You can often recognize text being outlined left and numeric to the right.